# How to execute an external program, sending data to STDIN and capturing STDOUT?

Tags: php, popen

In my PHP script I have a variable `$pkcs7_bin` that I would like to transform through `openssl`.

Assuming I have my input in a file, I could do this with bash:

```
cat in.pkcs7 | openssl pkcs7 -inform DER > out.pkcs7
```

I would like to do the same in PHP such as:

```
$exit_status execute('openssl pkc7 -inform DER', $pkcs7_bin, $pkcs7_out);
```

Of course I do not want to use intermediate files.

Is this a simple way to do it?

Currently I have written this:

```
function execute($process, $stdin, &$stdout)
{
    ob_start();
    $handle = popen($process, 'w');
    $write = fwrite($handle, $stdin)
    &$stdout = ob_get_clean();
    pclose($handle);
}
```

But I realized that what the output flushed on my screen is not captured by `ob_start` :(

Comment: I don't know much about openSSL, but there is [openSSL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.openssl.php) extension in PHP. Is it not enough for your use case?

Comment: Thanks, I know this, but this is not what my question is about, tags are `php` and `popen`, not `openssl` :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how get the output from process opend by popen in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15988369/how-get-the-output-from-process-opend-by-popen-in-php)

Comment: @Chipster, this is not a duplicate. Look at the title of my question. I want to pipe STDIN to a command and get the result from STDOUT. the question you linked does not address this problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For generic use for console commands, what you are after is `shell_exec()` - Execute command via shell and return the complete output as a string

Note that for your use case, the OpenSSL functions that PHP provides may do what you need to do "natively" without worrying about spawning a shell (often disabled for security reasons)

Anyway, back to shell_exec():

`cat in.pkcs7 | openssl pkcs7 -inform DER > out.pkcs7`

could be done as 
    // obtain input data somehow.  you could just
    // shell_exec your original command, using correct
    // paths to files and then read out.pkcs7 with file_get_contents()
    $infile=file_get_contents("/path/to/in.pcks7");
    $result=shell_exec("echo ".$infile." | openssl pcks7 - inform DER");

May/will/does need tweeking with `"` and `'` to handle special characters in the `$infile` content. Change `$infile` to be whatever input you'd be sending anyway, just be sure to quote/escape properly if needed.

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I do no want to use intermediate file. In your answer you use $infile which I would like to be pipped from PHP

Comment: @nowox - with what I posted, `$infile` can contain anything you like...

Comment: What if `$infile` contains `u | sh -c "rm -rf /"`?

Comment: @nowox - well, if you really want to have it contain that... feel free.